# Route every request through index.php (including images, css, etc.)

Tags: php, url, routes

(php newbie here)

I'm writing a very simple router for a mostly static marketing website.  So far, I have every request that doesn't match a file go through my index.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in my index.php, I decide what to output.  This is working pretty well.

But what happens if a user browses specifically to a file I don't want them to go to?  It won't go through my index.php.  So I could remove that condition... but what about css files?  I'm guessing I could include those as well.  But then... what about images?

I'm guessing there's a better way that I just don't know about yet.

(One request:  Please don't suggest using a framework.  I'd like to learn how things work before I use somebody else's code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Rewrite condition to include a list of excluded filetypes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpg|gif)$
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

So if I'm understanding correctly, I would replace "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" with what's in your answer, right?  And if I'm understanding correctly, this would route every single request besides images through my index.php.  Is that correct?  And finally, am I correct that css pages and stuff can be included through the index page?

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes thats correct I'll edit my answer, and anything you don't list in (png|jpg|gif) will be passed thru to index.php.